# Emergency access accounts in domain *.onmicrosoft.com

Tags: azure-active-directory

Let's say you have setup an AD directory with a custom domain named mysite.com. To add the recovery accounts there are only two option:

1. Create a user
2. Invite a user

If you create a user it will be on mysite.com, for example user23@mysite.com.
If you invite a user, for example, a user whose email is sample@example.com, the user created will be something like sample_example.com#EXT#@mysite.com.

My questions are:

- What is it meant by [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/security-emergency-access) that the emergency access accounts "should be cloud-only accounts that use the *.onmicrosoft.com domain"?

I do not see a way they have ".onmicrosoft.com", since methods 1 and 2 always end up with the custom domain.

- Why is it preferred an account on ".onmicrosoft.com" over one on the custom domain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A domain name is an important part of the identifier for many Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) resources: it's part of a user name or email address for a user, part of the address for a group, and is sometimes part of the app ID URI for an application. A resource in Azure AD can include a domain name that's owned by the Azure AD organization (sometimes called a tenant) that contains the resource. Only a Global Administrator can manage domains in Azure AD.

When we signup to azure Every new Azure AD tenant comes with an initial domain name, .onmicrosoft.com. You can't change or delete the initial domain name.but you can add your organization's names. Adding custom domain names helps you to create
While creating a user account you will be having an option to choose the domain.

As mentioned in the document if you create an emergency user account with custom domain we need to take care about the below points.

•   The user accounts are federated, and federation is currently unavailable because of a cell-network break or an identity-provider outage. For example, if the identity provider host in your environment has gone down, users might be unable to sign in when Azure AD redirects to their identity provider.

•   The administrators are registered through Azure AD Multi-Factor Authentication, and all their individual devices are unavailable or the service is unavailable. Users might be unable to complete Multi-Factor Authentication to activate a role. For example, a cell network outage is preventing them from answering phone calls or receiving text messages, the only two authentication mechanisms that they registered for their device.

•   The person with the most recent Global Administrator access has left the organization. Azure AD prevents the last Global Administrator account from being deleted, but it does not prevent the account from being deleted or disabled on-premises. Either situation might make the organization unable to recover the account.

•   Unforeseen circumstances such as a natural disaster emergency, during which a mobile phone or other networks might be unavailable.

To avoid all the above scenarios, we require the emergency user account with default onmicrosoft.com domain.